# Clearfix causes display error with Webkit

Tags: css, webkit

I use a this CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 0
}
```

to move things onto a new line.  However, in Webkit, it causes a bunch of content to disappear and moves the box holding it to the bottom of the screen.  The trick works correctly in IE and Firefox.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide some code and a demo of this problem?  http://tinker.io/

Comment: Here is another clear method I prefer: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: What good is it to show us your `clearfix` "trick" without any context whatsoever?  Show the HTML code that this is supposed to "fix"!

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be in your code, which we can't see. But try using this clear fix. It works for me every time:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html